# Optimize Async Tornado code. Minimize the thread lock

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, couchdb, tornado

How can I minimize the thread lock with `Tornado`? Actually, I have already the working code, but I suspect that it is not fully asynchronous.

I have a really long task.
It consists of making several requests to `CouchDB` to get meta-data and to construct a final link. Then I need to make the last request to `CouchDB` and stream a file (from 10 MB up to 100 MB). So, the result will be the streaming of a large file to a client.

The problem that the server can receive 100 simultaneous requests to download large files and I need not to lock thread and keep recieving new requests (I have to minimize the thread lock).

So, I am making several synchronous requests (`requests` library) and then stream a large file with chunks with `AsyncHttpClient`.

The questions are as follows:

1) Should I use `AsyncHTTPClient` EVERYWHERE? Since I have some interface it will take quite a lot of time to replace all synchronous requests with asynchronous ones. Is it worth doing it?

2) Should I use `tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient`? Will the code run faster (file download, making requests)?

3) I see that `Python 3.5` introduced `async` and theoretically it can be faster. Should I use async or keep using the decorator `@gen.coroutine`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AsyncHTTPClient or CurlAsyncHTTPClient. Since the "requests" library is synchronous, it blocks the Tornado event loop during execution and you can only have one request in progress at a time. To do asynchronous networking operations with Tornado requires purpose-built asynchronous network code, like CurlAsyncHTTPClient.

Yes, CurlAsyncHTTPClient is a bit faster than AsyncHTTPClient, you may notice a speedup if you stream large amounts of data with it.

`async` and `await` are faster than `gen.coroutine` and `yield`, so if you have `yield` statements that are executed very frequently in a tight loop, or if you have deeply nested coroutines that call coroutines, it will be worthwhile to port your code.